# how to write a shortcut map in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to add a shortcut like I type :open_my_document, it become :e /var/book/document.txt.
how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a custom command, use `:command`:

```
:command Open_my_document e /var/book/document.txt
```

Then you can use:

```
:Open_my_document
```

Normally you can just type `:Ope` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and vim will complete the full command name.

Note that your command needs to start with a capital letter because only built-in vim commands can start with lower-case letters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like `:h cabbr` or `:h cmap`.

If you use `cabbr`, your text will not change once you enter your custom command.  If you use `cmap`, it will.  It's easier to just try both out to see which you'd rather use.

I don't know advantages/disadvantages of one or the other, personally, I use `cmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
map :open_my_document :e /var/book/document.txt
```